# Split a Javascript string

Tags: javascript, regex, split

**Available Times:**
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
8-12
12-5
**Other type of contact:**
SMS
**Unavailable Times:**
Thursday
8-12

I want to split the above string as three separate arrays
1st array = [Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
8-12
12-5]

2nd array = [SMS]

3rd array = [Thursday
8-12
]

I tried using split function, but dint work!
I appreciate your kind help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: At times "Other type of contact: SMS" and "Unavailable Times: Thursday 8-12" maybe present or not.

Comment: Does the OP mean `["Monday Tuesday Wednesday 8-12 12-5"]` or `["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "8-12", "12-5"]` and likewise for the two remaining ones ?.. **or** ... does the OP even mean a single array with three string items like ... `["Monday Tuesday Wednesday 8-12 12-5", "SMS", "Thursday 8-12"]`. The question arises since the OP did not provide a proper syntax of the expected result and three separate arrays each with just a single item does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006093/regular-expression-to-search-multiple-strings-textpad)

```js
let str = 'Available Times: Monday Tuesday Wednesday 8-12 12-5 Other type of contact: SMS Unavailable Times: Thursday 8-12'
let replace = str.replace('Available Times: ', '');
let arr = replace.split(/ Other type of contact: | Unavailable Times: /)
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this as long as the bold part of the string are always the same:

```
var s = "Available Times: Monday Tuesday Wednesday 8-12 12-5 Other type of contact: SMS Unavailable Times: Thursday 8-12"
var arr = []

arr.push(s.split(" Unavailable Times: ")[1])
s = s.split(" Unavailable Times: ")[0]

arr.unshift(s.split(" Other type of contact: ")[1])
s = s.split(" Other type of contact: ")[0]

arr.unshift(s.split("Available Times: ")[1])

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Does the OP mean `["Monday Tuesday Wednesday 8-12 12-5"]` or `["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "8-12", "12-5"]` and likewise for the two remaining ones ?.. **or** ... does the OP even mean a single array with three string items like ... `["Monday Tuesday Wednesday 8-12 12-5", "SMS", "Thursday 8-12"]`. The question arises since the OP did not provide a proper syntax of the expected result and three separate arrays each with just a single item does not make any sense.*

In case of just extracting the information as three separated string values the following regex might be of help ...

[`/Available Times:\s*(?<available>.*?)\s+Other type of contact:\s*(?<contact>.*?)\s+Unavailable Times:\s*(?<unavailable>.*?)\s*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/jVedS4/1)

1. With a simple [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) one would receive an array which holds the *match* itself followed by the results of the 3 [*capturing groups*](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups)
2. In order to just receive an array without the *match* one needs to [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array.
3. One also can make use of [*named capturing groups*](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) via [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and some [*Destructuring Assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

```js
const sampleData =
  'Available Times: Monday Tuesday Wednesday 8-12 12-5 Other type of contact: SMS Unavailable Times: Thursday 8-12';

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/jVedS4/1]
const regXGroups =
  /Available Times:\s*(?<available>.*?)\s+Other type of contact:\s*(?<contact>.*?)\s+Unavailable Times:\s*(?<unavailable>.*?)\s*$/;

console.log(
  sampleData.match(regXGroups)
);
console.log(
  sampleData.match(regXGroups).slice(1)
);

const {
  unavailable,
  available,
  contact,
} = regXGroups.exec(sampleData)?.groups ?? {};

console.log([available, contact, unavailable]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```